# EF Core - Get a System.ExecutionEngineException exception when using EF Core Migrate in asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have an asp.net webApi project where I have just added EF Core (2.0.2) to handle the SQLite datastore.

Whenever I have the processed recycled (ie edit web.config which causes the restart), I always get an exception (with either debug or release build) when I call the EF Core migration.

So if I call a route from say Postman, whether or not  I have Visual studio open, I see..

[image]

And then if I attach, I go to the line..

[image]

If I hit cancel, it seems to continue and then succeed if buit for debug, but fails in release. If I call the same route again, it then succeeds.

Has anyone else had this, or have any idea what the problem could be here, or have any advice on how to track it down?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is there a related inner exception?

Comment: No, the innerexception is null.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or work around for this issue?

Comment: @Thomas927 - I didn't, I'd have to go back and check this is till occurring...